# How do i store my link clicks permanently?

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var clicks = 0;
function onClick() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};
</script>

<center>
<button type="button" style="height: 40px; width: 200px" onClick="onClick()">
<a href="url">DOWNLOAD</a>
</button>
<p>Downloaded: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
</center>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample of what you want using SessionStorage. The click counter will persist even on refresh of page.

Also, on every click you can store it on server.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function clickCounter() {
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (sessionStorage.clickcount) {
            sessionStorage.clickcount = Number(sessionStorage.clickcount)+1;
        } else {
            sessionStorage.clickcount = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + sessionStorage.clickcount + " time(s) in this session.";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button">Click me!</button></p>
<div id="result"></div>
<p>Click the button to see the counter increase.</p>
<p>Close the browser tab (or window), and try again, and the counter is reset.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also use localStorage for this case. Local storage is more secure, and large amounts of data can be stored locally, without affecting website performance.

Unlike cookies, the storage limit is far larger (at least 5MB) and information is never transferred to the server.

Here is an example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function clickCounter() {
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.clickcount) {
            localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
        } else {
            localStorage.clickcount = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + localStorage.clickcount + " time(s).";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button">Click me!</button></p>
<div id="result"></div>
<p>Click the button to see the counter increase.</p>
<p>Close the browser tab (or window), and try again, and the counter will continue to count (is not reset).</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Jonasw: Thanks !. I agree !. 
Included a snippet for localStorage too. Just in case if it will help someone to find and compare both example in one place.

Comment: I don't know coding that much, i just want to make a simple download count for this button:                                                                      <body>
<p><button onclick="clickCounter()">
<a href="http://fileboxer.co.za/up/get.php?f=vJV8nGfw" style="text-decorations:none; color:inherit; font-size: 12pt" type="button">DOWNLOAD</button></p>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>

Comment: I just want every button click to be stored on my server (button refers to a link )
<body>
<p><button onclick="clickCounter()">
<a href="http://fileboxer.co.za/up/get.php?f=vJV8nGfw" style="text-decorations:none; color:inherit; font-size: 12pt" type="button">DOWNLOAD</button></p>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>

Comment: Then you can write a webservice(like RESTful services) which will update the counter by 1 everytime in your Database/Server.

Answer (score 0):

Read about *cookies* or *localstorage* if you want to keep it the data in your browser.

Comment: i want to keep it on  MySQL  server

Comment: Thats a comment. A 20k user should know that

Comment: Unfortunately that's a rounding error, I'm only at 19.988. I've still much to learn.

Comment: I am all new to this. and being in South Africa, no one can really teach me, except you guyz

Comment: I want every button click to be stored on my server (button refers to a link )
<body>
<p><button onclick="clickCounter()">
<a href="http://fileboxer.co.za/up/get.php?f=vJV8nGfw" style="text-decorations:none; color:inherit; font-size: 12pt" type="button">DOWNLOAD</button></p>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>